# Monitoring an Activity started with startActivity()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I use startActivity() to begin a new Activity within my application and would like to find a way to either poll for or be notified when the started Activity exits.  Is this possible?

Clarification:
The Intent passed into startActivity will be using ACTION_VIEW.

Answer (score 4):

[`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is the method you want to use.

After your `Activity` completes a callback will be made to the calling `Activity` for [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), where you can then process the returned data from the closed `Activity`.

The documentation for [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) details pretty well how you can do this.

Comment: There is something that concerns me about that method.  From the documentation:

"Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as ACTION_MAIN or ACTION_VIEW), you may not get the result when you expect."

Since I'll be using ACTION_VIEW most of the time, it sounds like this won't work.

Comment: What is it that you want to do when this `Activity` returns?

Comment: Basically, I need to immediately delete the file being viewed by the external activity; one use case would be that I want to open a JPG using the default viewer, then as soon as the default viewer is closed, I want to delete the  JPG.